# Multiprocessing writing to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pandas, multiprocessing

So what I am trying to do with the following code is to read a list of lists and put them through function called `checker` and then have `log_result` deal with the result of the function `checker`. I am trying to do this using multithreading because the variable name `rows_to_parse` in reality has millions of rows, so using multiple cores should speed up this process by a considerable amount.

The code at present moment doesn't work and crashes Python.

Concerns and Issues I have:

1. Want the existing df which held in the variable `df` to maintain the
   index throughout process because otherwise `log_result` will get
   confused as to which row needs updating.
2. I am quite certain that `apply_async` is not the appropriate
   multiprocessing function to perform this duty because I believe the
   order at which the computer reads and writes the df can possibly corrupt it???
3. I think that a queue may need to be set up to write and read `df`
   but I am unsure as to how I would go about doing that.

Thank you for any assistance.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

def checker(a,b,c,d,e):
    match = df[(df['a'] == a) & (df['b'] == b) & (df['c'] == c) & (df['d'] == d) & (df['e'] == e)]
    index_of_match = match.index.tolist()
    if len(index_of_match) == 1: #one match in df
        return index_of_match
    elif len(index_of_match) > 1: #not likely because duplicates will be removed prior to: if "__name__" == __main__:
        return [index_of_match[0]]
    else: #no match, returns a result which then gets processed by the else statement in log_result. this means that [a,b,c,d,e] get written to the df
        return [a,b,c,d,e]



def log_result(result, dataf):
    if len(result) == 1: #
        dataf.loc[result[0]]['e'] += 1 
    else: #append new row to exisiting df
        new_row = pd.DataFrame([result],columns=cols)
        dataf = dataf.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)


def apply_async_with_callback(parsing_material, dfr):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e in parsing_material:
        pool.apply_async(checker, args = (var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e), callback = partial(log_result,dataf=dfr))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #setting up main dataframe
    cols = ['a','b','c','d','e']
    existing_data = [["YES","A","16052011","13031999",3],
                    ["NO","Q","11022003","15081999",3],
                    ["YES","A","22082010","03012001",9]]

    #main dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(existing_data,columns=cols)

    #new data
    rows_to_parse = [['NO', 'A', '09061997', '06122003', 5],
                    ['YES', 'W', '17061992', '26032012', 6],
                    ['YES', 'G', '01122006', '07082014', 2],
                    ['YES', 'N', '06081992', '21052008', 9],
                    ['YES', 'Y', '18051995', '24011996', 6],
                    ['NO', 'Q', '11022003', '15081999', 3],
                    ['NO', 'O', '20112004', '28062008', 0],
                    ['YES', 'R', '10071994', '03091996', 8],
                    ['NO', 'C', '09091998', '22051992', 1],
                    ['YES', 'Q', '01051995', '02012000', 3],
                    ['YES', 'Q', '26022015', '26092007', 5],
                    ['NO', 'F', '15072002', '17062001', 8],
                    ['YES', 'I', '24092006', '03112003', 2],
                    ['YES', 'A', '22082010', '03012001', 9],
                    ['YES', 'I', '15072016', '30092005', 7],
                    ['YES', 'Y', '08111999', '02022006', 3],
                    ['NO', 'V', '04012016', '10061996', 1],
                    ['NO', 'I', '21012003', '11022001', 6],
                    ['NO', 'P', '06041992', '30111993', 6],
                    ['NO', 'W', '30081992', '02012016', 6]]


    apply_async_with_callback(rows_to_parse, df)
```

Comment: What is else: #no match, give it arguments to write to df supposed to be doing? I think if you  `return [a, b, c, d, e]` your code will actually complete but you will have other problems,  you  also never use dataf anywhere

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, i have amended the code. so `[a,b,c,d,e]` gets written to the df in the function `log_result`.

Comment: `partial(log_result,dataf=dfr)` does not match the signature of `log_results`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Updating DataFrames like this in MultiProcessing isn't going to work:

```
dataf = dataf.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
```

For one thing this is very inefficient (O(n) for each append so O(n^2) in total. The preferred way is to concat some objects together in one pass.

For another, and more importantly, dataf is not locking for each update, so there's no guarantee that two operations won't conflict (I'm guessing this is crashing python).

Finally, append doesn't act in place, so the variable `dataf` is discarded once the callback is finished!! and no changes are made to the parent `dataf`.

---

We could use [MultiProcessing list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) or a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict). list if you don't care about order or dict if you do (e.g. enumerate), as you must note that the values are returned not in a well-defined order from async.
(or we could create an object which implements Lock ourselves, see *[Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing)*.)
So the following changes are made:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(existing_data,columns=cols)
# becomes
df = pd.DataFrame(existing_data,columns=cols)
d = MultiProcessing.list([df])

dataf = dataf.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
# becomes
d.append(new_row)
```

Now, once the async has finished you have a MultiProcessing.list of DataFrames. You can concat these (and `ignore_index`) to get the desired result:

```
pd.concat(d, ignore_index=True)
```

Should do the trick.

---

Note: creating the newrow DataFrame at each stage is also less efficient that letting pandas parse the list of lists directly to a DataFrame in one go. Hopefully this is a toy example, really you want your chunks to be quite large to get wins with MultiProcessing (I've heard 50kb as a rule-of-thumb...), a row at a time is never going to be a win here.

---

Aside: You should avoid using globals (like df) in your code, it's much cleaner to pass them around in your functions (in this case, as an argument to checker).

Comment: If you don't reassign the DataFrame and never write to the same location twice, is it safe to write to it concurrently from multiple threads?

Comment: That should be fine on the MultiProcessing.list/dict, it handles the locking, so will be safe.