# How to preserve changes to pandas DataFrame when using multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, copy

I have a pandas DataFrame and I need to modify this based on some other data that I'm reading off of many files. To speed this up, I'm trying to do this in parallel using the built-in `multiprocessing` module.

I have a function that modifies the DataFrame. When called manually, this works fine and the DataFrame changes are preserved. When called in parallel, the changes are not preserved.

I know this is somehow related to the `SettingWithCopyWarning`, but I can't figure out how to work around the issue?

**How can I preserve the changes when using the multiprocessing module?**

I've created a MWE that illustrates the problem that I'm having.

```py
import multiprocessing

import pandas as pd

class Data:
    def __init__(self):

        self.data = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "ZAID": ["1001.00c", "92235.00nc"],
                "ZA": [1001, 92235],
                "T(K)": [293.6, 293.6]
            }
        )

        # This is the data that I don't know when creating the DataFrame
        # The content will be filled later using addData
        columns = {"NE": int, "length": int}
        for name, dtype in columns.items():
            self.data[name] = pd.Series(dtype=dtype)

    def addData(self, index):
        """
        add data to an index of the data frame
        """
        # read file and extract data
        NE = 1200
        length = 1234

        self.data.loc[index, "NE"] = NE
        self.data.loc[index, "length"] = length

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Learning pandas")

    dd = Data()
    dd.addData(0)  # This call *does* save the addition

    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        # This call *does not* save the additions
        pool.map(dd.addData, dd.data.index)
```

Comment: `dd.data.index`? It doesn't look like you are *adding* data, but `modifying` data since your `dd.data.index` has only one (existing) value.

Comment: Well, yes, but I'm modifying from a null value to some real value. If there is a better way to do this, please advise.

Comment: you tried using queue?

Comment: @EmersonPedroso I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i got from this guy i was same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550312/multiprocessing-writing-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @EmersonPedroso I'm not appending new rows to the data. I'm modifying data values in existing rows.

Comment: new rows append and for keep  last data need to dfold.merge(dfnew) i'm on the street now i'll do it as soon as i get to the office